# What were the things in Prisoner of Azkaban movie that foreshadowed HP6/HP7?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was JK Rowling referring to during the Prisoner of Azkaban DVD commentary?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/what-was-jk-rowling-referring-to-during-the-prisoner-of-azkaban-dvd-commentary)

**UPDATE**: Seems to be a duplicate of " [What was JK Rowling referring to during the Prisoner of Azkaban DVD commentary?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5426/what-was-jk-rowling-referring-to-during-the-prisoner-of-azkaban-dvd-commentary) " - please vote to close!

As per "*Prisoner of Azkaban DVD Extra*" ( Quoted at http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/list2004.html)

> Cuaron "put things in the [PoA] film that, without knowing it, foreshadow things that are going to happen in the final two books."

I'm assuming that this means things which were NOT in PoA book.

**If this is correct, does anyone know what those movie-specific foreshadowings in PoA were?**

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - seems that way. Voting to close

Comment: Wow, voting to close your own question...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - I think that's within the rules?

Comment: Well, if it let you...